pandas cut will influence groupby rows
I meet a pandas special behavior and wish to know why:
Version1: use groupby and reset_index directly
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col1': [4],
    'col2': [1],
    'col3': ['gg'],
    'uplift_ratio': [0.94],
    'p1': [1],
    'p2': [103],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['bucket_int'] = 2
print(df.groupby(by=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] + ['bucket_int']).agg({'p2': sum}).reset_index())

then the output will have only one row like below:
   col1    col2  col3  bucket_int  p2
0       4  1    gg           2   103

Version2: add pandas.cut
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col1': [4],
    'col2': [1],
    'col3': ['gg'],
    'uplift_ratio': [0.94],
    'p1': [1],
    'p2': [103],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_config={'uplift_buckets': [0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]}
df2['bucket'] = pd.cut(df2['uplift_ratio'], bins=data_config['uplift_buckets'])
df2['bucket_int'] = pd.cut(
    df2['uplift_ratio'], bins=data_config['uplift_buckets'],
    labels=list(range(len(data_config['uplift_buckets']) - 1))
)

df2.groupby(by=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'] + ['bucket_int']).agg({'p2': sum}).reset_index()

in this case, it will generate 4 rows like below:
   c1    c2  c3 bucket_int  p2
0       4  1    gg          0    0.000
1       4  1    gg          1    0.000
2       4  1    gg          2    103.000
3       4  1    gg          3    0.000

My question is why it will lead to multi rows in this case? thanks.

Use df2.groupby(by=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'] + ['bucket_int'], observed=True).agg({'p2': 'sum'})

thanks, do you know what happened inside pd.cut, is there any doc to describe it?

Reason is pd.cut create categorical, it is describe https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html
